# Find SQL Server Tables that have two specified column names

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to search tables in sql server for a table that has two specific column names ex (columnA and columnB).  I have a query that searches on one column name

```
SELECT name FROM sysobjects WHERE id IN 
( SELECT id FROM syscolumns WHERE name = 'columnA' )
```

I don't know how to modify this to search for two columns.

Comment: You've chosen a non-working answer.

Comment: you're right...I've changed the selection

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
SELECT name FROM sysobjects WHERE id IN 
( SELECT id FROM syscolumns WHERE name = 'columnA' )
and id in 
( SELECT id FROM syscolumns WHERE name = 'columnB' )
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 6):

This is the right way to do it:

```
select so.name 
from sysobjects so 
where so.type = 'U' -- it's a user's table
and exists (select * from syscolumns sc where sc.id = so.id and sc.name='columnA')
and exists (select * from syscolumns sc where sc.id = so.id and sc.name='columnB')
```

It's important to check that it's a user table. On the contrary you could find views, table valued functions and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
select syscolumns.id, sysobjects.name from syscolumns 
  join sysobjects so on sysobjects.id = syscolumns.id
 where exists (select 1 from syscolumns sc where sc.id = syscolumns.id and name = 'columnA') 
   and exists (select 1 from syscolumns sc2 where sc2.id = syscolumns.id and name = 'columnB')
```

Comment: I think you can't reference the table by its original name if you assigned it a different alias. (I'm talking about `sysobjects`.)